# Why reassigning const producing error in console only if we do that in code editor?

Tags: javascript, console

I wrote the following code in code editor to produce error:

```
const a = 1;
console.log(a);

const a = 1;  // Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'a' has already been declared
```

I did the same thing directly into console --

```
const a = 1; //undefined
const a = 1; //undefined
const a = 2; // undefined
a // 2
```

Why here error was not caught?

Comment: My Firefox console gives me `Uncaught SyntaxError: redeclaration of const a`

Comment: Are you using Chrome?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-92/#const-redeclaration

Comment: Yes. I am using chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using Chrome, this is by design. `const` redeclarations was intentionally implemented in Chrome Devtools 92 as a means to make it easier for developers to test code within the Chrome console (my emphasis):

> The Console now supports redeclaration of **const** statement, in addition
> to the existing **let** and **class** redeclarations. The inability to
> redeclare was a common annoyance for web developers who use the
> Console to experiment with new JavaScript code.
>
> - [Chrome Developer Blog](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-92/#const-redeclaration)

As the blog post points out, it enables you to redeclare `const` and other bindings you wouldn't usually be able to redeclare. This means something like:

```
> const a = 1;
```

```
> const a = 2;
```

is allowed as the two lines of code are executing in separate REPL scripts (indicated by the `>`), whereas performing:

```
> const a = 1;
  const a = 2;
x Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'a' has already been declared
```

is not allowed as this is redeclaring `const` within the one REPL script (multiple lines of code can be entered into the one command line using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>).
This change is only for the Chrome devtools console, and not for regular page scripts, which will throw a SyntaxError as expected if you try and redeclare `const`.