# Why can let declare variables repeatedly?

Tags: javascript, browser-console

Why can let declare variables repeatedly in the browser console?

I remember that I would have reported an error before. Is 21-year chrome based on that ECMA-specification?

> let a=1
> undefined
>
> let a=12
> undefined
>
> navigator.userAgent
> 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
> AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chro
> me/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36'

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Also related: [Why reassigning const producing error in console only if we do that in code editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69054932/5648954)

Answer (score 4):

The console environment has a number of odd quirks. It's not like a standard `<script>` tag on the page.

One of the quirks is these. The way it used to be in Chrome was, re-declarations of variables with `let` was not permitted - you'd get the expected error that the re-declaration is invalid syntax. But as of Chrome 80 or so (spring 2020), it [was changed to be permitted](https://dev.to/cooldashing24/chrome-now-allows-for-let-and-class-redeclarations-in-the-console-2m0f).

You still can't re-declare variables with `let` in a standard `<script>`, of course:

```js
let foo = 5;
let foo = 10;
```

Comment: Key bit from the linked post: "The inability to redeclare using let and class was a common annoyance amongst web developers who experiment new JavaScript code in the Console."

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is exactly where I am confused. The processing results of console and script are different. Very curious where did you know this? My English is not good, there may be grammatical errors, sorry

Comment: @andrewyin I knew this because I noticed the change when it happened more than a year ago, since I do a lot of typing in the console, and also sometimes check the Chrome release notes.

Comment: You must be a programming master. I hope that one day I can also become an excellent programmer. Do you have any recommended learning materials about javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redeclare a variable previously declared with `let` in strict mode. Please see: [What's the difference between using "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var).

Comment: How do you understand the temporary dead zone problem?